# Passing reference number to data controller

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass my reference data to controller via ajax. The controller didnt receive the data that's why it cannot return query.

This is my button upon click:

```
$('#inquire_t tbody').on('click', '#mensahe', function () {
    var refNumber = $(this).attr('value');
    // console.log(refNumber);
    getMessageThread(refNumber);

});//btn-message
```

this is my function:

```
function getMessageThread(refNumber) {
    console.log('This is the reference number: ' + refNumber);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/getMessageThread",
        type: "POST",
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
        data: refNumber,
        dataType: "TEXT",
        success: function (msg) {

        }//each
    });
}// getMessageThread
```

and this is my controller:

```
public function getAllMessage(Request $request) {
    $refNumber = $request -> get('refNumber');

    $messageThread = DB:: table('i_di_thread')
        -> select('message')
        -> where('refNumber', $refNumber)
        -> get();
    return view('showInquiries', ['messageThread'=> $messageThread]);
}
```

I wanted to get the refNumber value controller to use to my where query

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `$(this).attr('value')`, use `$(this).val()`.

[Link to API for `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Comment: Im getting the refNumber by using $this.attr('value') but when Im passing it to the controller via $.ajax it did not pass the data. The rerfNumber inside the controller is still null in value

Comment: @lalalalalallala do you think you could improve the question by adding a code snippet that minimally shows how the value is null when the click handler is invoked?

Comment: The query does not return any data and when I print the value of refnumber inside the controller it display null value. But when I try to assign a specific value for refnumber inside the controller for example ( refNumber = '000009' ) it returns the right value.